# Prioritizing the wordpress comments

Tags: comments

I want to change the order of the post comments i.e the main comment should be in desc order (recent comment should display first) but all the reply to the main comment should be in inc order(latest reply should display at last).
   I know from admin panel->settings->discussion we can change the order of the comment but that order will be for all the comment.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried with last wordpress and if I change the order in admin panel->settings->discussion it change only the order of first level comment, the replies are still in chronological order.